# xmerl does not recognize a few characters

Tags: xml, erlang

I have an application that uses xmerl to parse XML content coming from external users. That means, any string can come from them.

I use xmerl_scan:string/1 to parse this xml, but I started get some errors when the xml contains some '\' something on the text.

For example:

```
XML = "<tag>say.com\brothers</tag>",
xmerl_scan:string(XML).
```

it results in:

```
3266- fatal: {error,{wfc_Legal_Character,8}}
** exception exit: {fatal,{{error,{wfc_Legal_Character,8}},
                       {file,file_name_unknown},
                       {line,1},
                       {col,15}}}
 in function  xmerl_scan:fatal/2
 in call from xmerl_scan:scan_char_data/5
 in call from xmerl_scan:scan_content/11
 in call from xmerl_scan:scan_element/12
 in call from xmerl_scan:scan_document/2
 in call from xmerl_scan:string/2
```

My question is: did anyone have this same problem already? How can I solve this?

I know this will also raise some kind of exceptions when I have:

\b
\e
\f
\v
\x
\0 .. \7

in my string.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `erlsom` found here: http://erlsom.sourceforge.net/erlsom.htm , i have personally found it more stable and direct compared with `xmerl`

Comment: My app is composed by a lot of components and all of them already make  use of xmerl. Changing to erlsom is not an option, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you have above, this is a violation of the XML specification for well-formedness:

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Char

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
     /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
```

In Erlang, the backslash character is used for escape sequences.  "\b" is an escape sequence for character 8 (the backspace character), so instead of meaning `"say.com\brothers"` it means: `"say.com"` (backspace) `"rothers"`.

The problem is that character 8 is not in the allowed list, so it needs to be escaped... XML escaped, not Erlang escaped... to make the XML valid.

When the string comes in from an external user, this will not be a problem.  The backslash escaping is only used in the process where the literal in Erlang source is converted to the string in memory.  If you read in an external string containing a backslash, you should see that it appears double when you print it: `"\\"` is the escape sequence for a literal backslash.  So, `"<tag>say.com\brothers</tag>"` would appear as `"<tag>say.com\\brothers</tag>"`.

If you escape the backslash, it works correctly.

```
> xmerl_scan:string("<tag>say.com\\brothers</tag>").
{{xmlElement,tag,tag,[],
             {xmlNamespace,[],[]},
             [],1,[],
             [{xmlText,[{tag,1}],1,[],"say.com\\brothers",text}],
             [],"/root",undeclared},
 []}
```

This appears to just be a problem with the way you are testing and should not be a problem for external data.  However, if the user **does** pass invalid XML, it will cause an exception as you've observed.  To handle that case, you need to explicitly check for it by trapping exits or using `catch`.

Comment: Hi...thanks for the explanation. The text is coming to my app through socket. So, it comes as a binary stream which I transform with binary_to_list and then parse using xmerl_scan.

I'll see what I can do to manage that.

Comment: binary_to_list should be dealing with this for you: if a backslash character comes in, it will automatically be `"\\"`.  Perhaps they have a similar problem on the sending end: the same backslash encoding method is used in a variety of languages.

Comment: Turned out that another component in Java, using JAXB, was creating this invalid XML and sending to my erlang application. JAXB has an issue (since 2009) that enables creation of XML containing control characters, like '\b', but throws exception when unmarshalling them.
This JAVA component created the invalid XML and sent to the Erlang App to process, hence the problem is in JAXB.